# how to add overlay image on google maps with rotation angle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Currently I added heatmap and markers, finding difficult to add overlay image on google maps with rotated angle.

here is the image to add as overlay `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png`

Coordinates and ration angle for overlay image

```
{
  "latitudeLowerLeftCorner": 36.155632225,
  "longitudeLowerLeftCorner": -115.128414118,
  "latitudeUpperRightCorner": 36.158216031,
  "longitudeUpperRightCorner": -115.122749292,
  "rotationDegrees": 25
}
```

Below is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heatmaps</title>
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .heatmap_area {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 700px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .heatmap_area_top {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }

    .heatmap_canvas {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 500px !important;
    }

    .map_range {
        width: 150px !important;
        display: inline-block !important;
        margin-left: 5px;
        position: relative;
        top: 6px;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<body>
<div class="heatmap_area" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="panel" class="heatmap_area_top">

        <span class="inline_block mar_right_20 mar_bot_10">Display markers: <input ng-change="toggleMarkers(locationMarkers)" ng-model="locationMarkers" ng-init="locationMarkers = true" type="checkbox"></span>
        <span class="inline_block mar_right_20 mar_bot_10">
            Opacity:
            <input class="map_range" type="range" ng-model="opacitySlider" ng-change="changeOpacity(opacitySlider)" min="0" max="1" step="0.1">{{opacitySlider}}
        </span>
        <span class="inline_block mar_bot_10">
            Radius:
            <input class="map_range" type="range" ng-model="radiusSlider" ng-change="changeRadius(radiusSlider)" min="10" max="60" step="10">{{radiusSlider}}
        </span>

    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" class="heatmap_canvas"></div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        // Adding Data Points
        var map, pointarray, heatmap;
        var markers = [];

        var taxiData = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.15781968185988, -115.12381247127779),
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.157096435501884, -115.12630456901275),
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.157439633757996, -115.1250151287446),
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.15743926433815, -115.12501704727082)

        ];



        $scope.initialize = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });

            heatmap.setMap(map);
            heatmap.set('radius', 40);
            heatmap.set('opacity', 0.9);

            var locations = [
                ['3', 36.15743945700828, -115.12501635678582],
                ['9', 36.1570964377607, -115.12630456858307],
                ['10', 36.15781923847604, -115.12381119140973]
            ];

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var iconBase = '';
            var marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: iconBase + ''
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    };
                })(marker, i));
            }

            // auto center
            function AutoCenter() {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
                    bounds.extend(marker.position);
                });
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
            AutoCenter();
        }
        $scope.initialize();

        $scope.radiusSlider = 40;
        $scope.opacitySlider = 0.9;
        
        // heat map opacity change
        $scope.changeRadius = function () {
            heatmap.set('radius', $scope.radiusSlider);
        }

        // heat map opacity change
        $scope.changeOpacity = function () {
            heatmap.set('opacity', $scope.opacitySlider);
        }

        // toggle map markers function
        $scope.toggleMarkers = function (mapMarkers) {
            if (mapMarkers == false) {
                for (var i = 0, n = markers.length; i < n; ++i) {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0, n = markers.length; i < n; ++i) {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question ? . you have error ?

Comment: @scaisEdge am not able to add overlay image